# rxjs timer still running after subject complete()

Tags: typescript, rxjs, timer

I have the following code to achieve 2 things in my Angular 8 project.

1. Api call every 30 seconds which I am using rxjs timer to keep track of.
2. Whenever I receive data via websocket, I want to call the same api and reset the timer to 30 seconds.

Problem:
It seems that the timer is still running when I navigate away from the page as I still can see the api calls in the network. I am not sure is this link to takeUntil leak, please help!

```
import {Observable, Subject, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {finalize, takeUntil, takeWhile, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

countdown = 30;
receivedWS = false;
private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
    this._networkService.getEventListener().pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe((res) =>          {
      if (res) {
        this.receivedWS = true;
        this.myService.getUsers().then(() => this.receivedWS = false);
      }
    });

    this._timer();
}

 private _timer(): void {
    timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.countdown = 30;
        this.myService.getUsers(); //api call
        this._timer();
      }),
      takeWhile(() => this.countdown > 0 && this.receivedWS = false),
      takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
      tap(() => this.countdown--)
    ).subscribe();
 }


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll.next(true);
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
}
```

What I have tried:
I have tried to explicitly unsubscribe the subject but instead got an error UnsubscriptionErrorImpl.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll.next(true);
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
    this._unsubscribeAll.unsubscribe();
  }
```

[UnsubscriptionErrorImpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRmEr.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried my solution already?

Answer (score 0):

**Why doesn't your code work as expected?**

When a user leaves the page, `OnDestroy` is called and `this._unsubscribeAll.next(true)` is invoked. This triggers the `finalize()` operator inside the `_timer()` method. At the end of the `finalize` clause, you call `this._timer()`, which means that you resubscribe to your timer and it will restart emitting values (for an indefinite time).

**How can you achieve what you want?**

I recommend you to build up your code differently. Please check out this

**[Working Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zba3ua?file=src/main.ts)**

or take a look at my code below and the comments therein:

```
timerIntervalInMillis = 30_000;

stopTimerSubject = new Subject<void>();
restartTimerSubject = new Subject<void>();

unsubscribeAllSubject = new Subject<void>();

/* - timer$ makes an emission every xy milliseconds, yet its pipe...
   - ...unsubscribes when stopTimerSubject is triggered
   - ...resubscribes when restartTimerSubject is triggered
   - ...unsubscribes for good when unsubscribeAllSubject is triggered */

timer$ = timer(this.timerIntervalInMillis, this.timerIntervalInMillis).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.stopTimerSubject),
  repeat({ delay: () => this.restartTimerSubject }),
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAllSubject)
);

ngOnInit(): void {
  // The pipe below takes care of the incoming websocket data:
  const webSocketObs$ = this._networkService.getEventListener().pipe(
    filter((data) => !!data),
    tap((data) => console.log('Data from Websocket:', data)),
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAllSubject)
  );

  // The pipe below gets triggered if
  // - data from websocket comes in
  // - or if a timer-tick occured
  merge(webSocketObs$, this.timer$)
    .pipe(
      // Stop the timer before the API-request is made:
      tap(() => this.stopTimerSubject.next()),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.myService.getUsers().pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAllSubject),
          tap((data) => {
            console.log('Fetched Users:', data);
            // On request completion: Restart of the reset timer:
            this.restartTimerSubject.next();
          })
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAllSubject)
    )
    .subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribeAllSubject.next();
}
```